# Bypass Pattern lock without minimum or no touch of mobile

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens

I have android mobile with Android Lollipop 5.1.1 and I want to unlock the mobile without working on mobile. I had added pattern before screen damage.

Phone details:

1. Touch of mobile is damages and I can hardly use touch so working on cell is not possible. (I believe) I can type digit 3 on cell.
2. I tried to unlock device with ADM (http://trendblog.net/how-to-bypass-android-phone-lock-screen-pattern-pin-password/) but cell dont display option to fill pin to unlock
3. I have access to Google account and can install any apps.
4. Memory card can be inserted into mobile.
5. Internet is working on my cell.

I can do below thing with touch:

1. I can drag-down the top notification area of cell.
2. I can enable/disable hot-spot of cell.
3. I can receive calls on cell.

Please ask in comments if more details are required.

> In summary, I want to unlock or bypass pattern of mobile by using
>   computer or USB or Google account. How it can be possible and I want
>   to do without factory reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem.I purchased a OTG cable and connected my mouse. I easily unlock the pattern and can do all things with mouse from typing to call etc.

Now i can access my cell with mouse till i get confirmation from service center about availability of touch combo :)